# Metric spaces and distance functions.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I need to provide an example of a space of points **X** and a distance function **d**, such that the following properties hold:

1. **X** has a countable dense subset
2. **X** is uncountably infinite and has only one limit point
3. **X** is uncountably infinite and every point of **X** is isolated

I'm really bad with finding examples... Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

(I got the third one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, hint: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable set.

For the third question, hint: think about the discrete metric on a space.

For the second question: Let $X=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\:|\: x>1 \mbox{ or }x=\frac{1}{n}, n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}\}\cup\{0\}$. Let

- $d(x,y)=1$ if $x> 1$ or $y>1$,
- $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ if $x\leq 1$ and $y\leq 1$.

Comment: I found an example that *should* work for question two.

Answer (score 2):

For $(1)$, consider $(X,d)=(\mathbb{R},|.|)$, since $\mathbb{R}$ has $\mathbb{Q}$ the set of rational numbers as a countable subset.